# Raspberry Pi - How to measure 2 resistor values with GPIO

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio

Is it possible to measure 3 specific resistor values by using GPIO / Without using a full ADC setup?

I have an alarm sensor that I want to hook up to my GPIO. This sensor has 3 specific resistors value, based on it's state:

- 1) Normal - 4k7
- 2) Alarm  - 9k3
- 3) Tamper - infinite.

Due to long lines, I would prefer 12V power on one side.

I would like to be able to detect these states by 2 normal GPIO input pins.

Is that even possible? What would be the schematic needed for this?

Or is the only solution to use (external) ADC's?

I am thinking about a voltage diver with resistors and a 1N4148 diode to clip it to 3v3. But so far my results are unfruitfull.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually is ADC to solve this. GPIO has no capability at all to do such measurements. It's a question to electrical engineering SE department.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you have three levels to measure. If we had two we could use a simple resistor divider setup to make (say) the 4k7 and 9k3 outputs on the sensor to logic 0 (<=0.8V) or logic 1 (>=1.3V) on a single GPIO pin. We could do this on two GPIO pins if we had two "independent samples" of the sensor output rather than one.

Given the above it is possible to design some simple logic network to do the comparisons but as the other comment mentions you're off into the realms of electronics.

ADC is the simplest way to go if you want to stay in the software domain. The are other SBC devices e.g. ESP8266 which have onboard ADC functionality and built-in Wifi https://esp8266-projects.org/2015/03/internal-adc-esp8266/ or you can hook up an add-on ADC to the Rpi for example https://learn.adafruit.com/raspberry-pi-analog-to-digital-converters

Good luck